# Cannot start XAMPP on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: apache2, lamp, ssl, phpmyadmin, xampp

When I try to start XAMPP with sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start command it gives me a message like this.

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.7.7...
XAMPP: Another web server daemon with SSL is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
XAMPP: Couldn't start MySQL!
XAMPP: XAMPP-ProFTPD is already running.
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

What is this and how can I find what was this another web server daemon with SSL.
How to stop this server ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a peculiar error you will get if you run XAMPP in LINUX.

**Assumption**: XAMPP is unzipped @ `/opt/` folder.

If you get the error "XAMPP: Another web server daemon with SSL is already running" when you run `./lampp start`. Simply follow the steps below to get rid of this error:

1. Open the file `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`.
2. Search the `Listen 80` and change it to some other port (e.g. `Listen 2145`)  (Line No. 40).
3. Open the file `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-ssl.conf`.
4. Search the `Listen 443` and change it to some other port (e.g. `Listen 16443`) (Line No. 39).
5. Open the file `/opt/lampp/lampp`
6. Search for the port `testport 80` and replace it to `testport 2145`. Also change the `testport 443` to `testport 16443`. (Happens to be the Line No. 197, 214)
7. Now go and run `/opt/lampp/lampp start`. It should work now.

*Note:* Line numbers may be different.

Comment: Tnx bro.. :) Is there any way to stop that previously ruining server ?

Comment: That depends on which server it is, if any daemon process is using it,chances are less,first you need to know that which process is using the port by default.

Comment: This is the error i am getting if i click on phpmyadmin page in xampp. Error MySQL said: Documentation #2002 - No such file or directory The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Answer (score 3):

I have similar problem and found the issue caused another service already running on port 443 (SSL).

Check running listener: `sudo netstat -tunap | grep LISTEN`. Mine had `vmware-hostd` and `cupsd` listed.

Refer to http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html, we need turn off lamp's SSL service using the command `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stopssl`, which deactivates the SSL support permanently.

Now you can start xampp: `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

Comment: Changing ports to 2145 and 16443 didn't work for me. This did, and I need no ssl.. thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the terminal, execute `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp disablessl`. This should disable ssl, after which xampp will start successfully again.

Comment: Worked like a charm. But is there any downside of disabling ssl in Xampp?

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 16.04

1. First use the command `nmap localhost` and check whether port no.443 is running.
2. If it's running then use command `sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:443)`
3. Then open xampp control panel and start the apache server from there also.
4. It will start running.
5. Or you can also navigate to  the `/opt/lampp`
6. Then start it by giving command `./sudo xampp start`

It finally works